# Golang. Caching active users in global var/context. Its a good idea?

Tags: caching, web-applications, go

We have a web app in which data is loaded from mysql database.
Active users make a request every second.
`http.Handler` on each request retrieves same data from db.
I want to save last 100(or 200) in global app memory and first will try to check this by key in cookies. If user not in cache then make request to db and add data to cache.
The same approach can be used with other frequently requested data.

**I want to know what gophers think about this approach.**
I would be grateful for your advice and useful links.

Comment: "Potentially". 1 req per second is not a lot (how many concurrent users?) and it may be faster to just hit the DB. Tweak your indexes + cache sizing. Storing in memory might be acceptable (a mutex-protected `map[sessionID]data`) but you would need a way to evict members (which would require timestamping + locking during eviction). Redis (via `SETEX`) likely to be better. I would benchmark the "check Redis, doesn't exist, check mySQL, respond, then add to Redis" pipeline carefully: you might increase client latency by adding a cache.

Comment: but it is not a golang question.